# I want to be able to open images and PDFs in FireBaseStorege

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I am using FirebaseStorage with Flutter.

I can open jpegs and other images, but I am having trouble opening PDFs.

Is there a good way to do this as I want to change the behavior depending on the file extension?

Comment: Don't repost the same problem multiple times please. At best it'll get closed, but it may actually get you banned from the site. Instead, edit your original question to clarify the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Sorry! I'll be careful next time!